# Let $S=\{x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2| \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3}<1\}$, prove $S$ is a open set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S=\{x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2| \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3}<1\}$, prove $S$ is a open set.

Let $(x_1,y_1)\in S$, $r=min\{d((0,0),(x_1,y_1),d((x_1,y_1),\sqrt{3-\frac{3x^2}{2}})$

I need to show $B(r,(x_1,x_2))\subset S$

Let $(a,b)\in B(r,(x_1,x_2))$, then $d((a,b),(x_1,x_2))<r$

In this step i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Other way i was think, is define a function f(x,y), but i don't know how to use this method, (by function)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}2+\frac{y^2}3$. Then $f$ is continuous. Since $S=f^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,1)\bigr)$ and since $(-\infty,1)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$, $S$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The reason why $S=f^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,1)\bigr)$ is because\begin{align}f^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,1)\bigr)&=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\,f(x,y)\in(-\infty,1)\right\}\\&=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\,\frac{x^2}2+\frac{y^2}3<1\right\}\\&=S.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Jose, very clear. One question why $S=f^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,1)\bigr)$? Thanks

Comment: I can't see your comment, (Disapear) :S

Comment: @Bvss12 I've edited my answer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Jose!